# WPF combobox saving duplicate entries in database via SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, combobox

So, I'm converting some of my comboboxes to editable comboboxes because the customer wants to freely enter in new entries.  The comboboxes are populated by lookup tables with entity framework, and the new entries need to be added to the lookup table.  I've extended the combobox to generate an event when focus leaves the combobox that adds the new entry to the table:

```
private void CollectionComboBox_NewItem(object sender, NewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var newItem = new Collection() { Name = e.Text };
    _context.Collections.Add(newItem);
    e.Item = newItem;
}
```

This all seems to work well, but to get this to work, I had to switch binding to the entity from using SelectedValue to SelectedItem because the validator on the control fires because there is no ID assigned to the new record yet.

The problem comes when saving the record is that already existing items get another record added to the database.  I know it is related to switching to SelectedItem and not my custom combobox because it exhibits the same behavior with normal combobox.

My Combobox XAML:

```
<dock:EditableComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="CollectionComboBox" Margin="12,5,18,0"
          NewItem="CollectionComboBox_NewItem" MaxLength="100"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValuePath="CollectionID" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
          x:FieldModifier="private"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Collection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <dock:EditableComboBox.Text>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <gui:RequiredComboValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </dock:EditableComboBox.Text>
</dock:EditableComboBox>
```

CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionViewSource"
                      d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance storeAndForward:Collection, CreateList=True}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <windowsBase:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: `I've extended the combobox to generate an event when focus leaves the combobox that adds the new entry to the table` - You're putting a responsibility in the UI layer which doesn't belong to the UI layer. Handle this at the ViewModel level instead.

Comment: Also, it's not entirely clear how you're defining items that already exist. What do your entities look like? How are you loading them?